# Why does my Photoshop CS6 timeline have a different layout?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm doing a tutorial, and I noticed my timeline is quite different from the one in the video:

This is mine:

[image]

This is the tutorial's:

[image]

**The first problem is that I can't find the `Add Videos` button in my timeline.**

The second is that when I import videos from the top bar `File`, the videos become layers instead of whole videos.

I hope someone can tell me what's wrong with my Photoshop!

Comment: Please use comments to reply to an answer if it wasn't quite what you were looking for

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your issue of not seeing timeline options.

Answer (score 6):

The top image is a **Frame** animation.

The bottom image is a **Timeline** animation.

To switch between frame and timeline, click the menu on the Timeline Panel and choose the other option...

[image]

You can also choose whether you want a frame or timeline animation before creating the animation:

[image]

### NOTE!

**In order to create video timelines** you **MUST** have the "Extended" version of Photoshop. The standard version does not offer the video timeline features.

Comment: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RnEv4.gif) hello
I don't see button convert video time line
i used Photoshop cs6

Comment: You need the **extended** version of Photoshop to create video timelines.

Answer (score -2):

I've the same issue and I've read that reinstalling Photoshop solves the problem. I haven't tried yet, though.

There is also the possibility of not having the Extended version installed.